# Display the result of a query in a JTextField's value

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jtextfield

I want to display the new id from database  in a jTextField but it dosen't..
this is  my code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

    try {
        DB con=new DB();
        con.connecte();

        String req = "SELECT Max(num) FROM condidat";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(req);
        int num = rs.getInt("num");
        int nvNum=num+1;
        txt_num.setText(valueOf(nvNum));

        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ajouter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ajouter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what is going wrong?

Comment: nothing apear in my jTextField with the  jTextField.setText()

Comment: 1) Did you add a System.out.println(...) statement to your code to verify the value returned from the SQL query? 2) If a value is displayed, then the problem is you don't have a reference to the text field you added to the GUI. Maybe you have a local and an instance variable of the same name.

Comment: merci but it's not working

Comment: If you are getting an error, please post the error message.

Comment: no i got nothing,just what i want to display in the jTextField does not

Answer (score 2):

You don't call `ResultSet.next()` and the column in the `ResultSet` will not be called `num` but `Max(num)`, if you want a better name, change your query/code this way using `AS` in your query:

```
String req = "SELECT Max(num) AS maxnum FROM condidat";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(req);
if (rs.next()) {
   int num = rs.getInt("maxnum");
   ...
}
```

Remember that the ResultSet starts pointing before the first record, so next() must always be called at least one time (and this can also be useful to verify that there is actual data, it will return `false` if there are no more records). After that if, the `ResultSet` is ready to be used and it points to the first record.

Edit:

Since it looks like the `actionPerformed` is not even called, did you register this class as a listener to some `JComponent`, for example a button?

```
JButton b = new Button("Click me");
b.addActionListener(this);
```

If you click this button, and all this code is in the same class, the `actionPerformed` will be called.

Comment: thank you so much it's a good idea but nothing apear in the jTextField ! is it correct to put that code in the actionPerformed ???

Comment: Not much, especially it's not a good idea to perform the db connection there, it's the slower operation, even slower than executing the query. Usually you try to do only the minimum necessary stuff inside event callbacks like `actionPerformed`, there could be other listeners waiting to be called and you are delaying their execution.

Comment: @ViaTrasViaTras please add the code for `valueOf` to your question, there could be a problem there too :) It looks like it return an empty string.

Comment: I tested that with a simple instruction without connection to database I put just jTextField.setText("test") and it dosen't work

Comment: Is the textfield displayed correctly in your panel/frame/etc ?  `txt_num.setText("test")` must work.

Comment: Or you could update your answer adding the rest of the code, we can't spot errors if we can't see the code :)

Comment: the problem is that I am confused ,where should I put txt_num.setText("test") ,I tried to put it in actionPerformed  !

Comment: Ok, wait. `actionPerformed` is called only when for example the button where you added this class as listener is pressed, did you add the listener, right? I'm updating my answer with instructions.

Comment: and if I want to display a value in the jtextField when the frame load  how to do that??

Comment: Oh ok, so you **don't** need actionPerformed, just add the code after you have added all components to your panel/frame. First create and add all the graphical components then execute the query and set the textfield.

Comment: I put it as u say but it gives me package does not exist

Comment: @ViaTrasViaTras the package of your class? did you move the file?

Comment: package JtextField? It's the name of you package? Bad name... I need the full code...

Comment: I don't know if we can solve it this way... let's see if the chat link pops up...

Comment: anyway thanks for the idea of maximum,thank you for your effort.

Comment: Ok, looks like you have multiple issue in your code other than the ones i fixed above, can i recommend to take it slowly and try with smaller pure java programs before starting with swing? Also, if you need a book check *"Thinking in Java"*.

Answer (score 0):

change your integer value to a string because jTextField display only text
this way:
txt_num.setText(Integer.toString(nvNum));